# Showing that a simply connected proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is not conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

So far, I have said that if $U$ is proper, open and simply connected, then its complement contains an open set. Suppose $f$ is a conformal equivalence form $\mathbb{C}$ tp $U$. Consider the induced meromorphic function on the Riemann sphere. By Casorati-Weierstrass, since the image does not include the set missed in $\mathbb{C}-U$, so the singularity at infinity is a pole. Since $f$ is bijective and analytic, then by the Valency Theorem the pole must be simple.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: Can you use the Riemann mapping theorem? This would reduce the problem to the case $U=\mathbb{D}$.

Comment: No, I'm not wanting to do that.

Comment: $U$ could be the complement of the negative real axis. Its complement does not contain an open set.